# nested collections

Tags: vba, collections

Consider the following code:

```
Sub NestedCollections()
    Dim col1 As Collection
    Dim col2 As Collection
    Dim col3 As Collection

    Set col1 = New Collection
    Set col2 = New Collection
    Set col3 = New Collection

    col2.Add "a"
    col2.Add "b"
    col2.Add "c"

    col3.Add "d"
    col3.Add "e"
    col3.Add "f"

    col1.Add col2
    col1.Add col3

    col1.Item(2).Add col3

    Set col1 = Nothing
    Set col2 = Nothing
    Set col3 = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you add watch to "col1", and expand "item(2)", you'll notice that "item(4)" keeps on expanding.  Why is this happening?

Cheers,
Marek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything works normally, up until `col1.Item(2).Add col3` is executed.

Beyond that, `col1.Item(2)` is `col3` as per this instruction:

```
col1.Add col3
```

By adding `col3` to `col1.Item(2)`, you're adding a pointer to `col3` to... `col3`, which is why it "keeps expanding" - the 4th item of `col3` is `col3` itself:

```
col3.Add "d"   'col1.Item(2)(1)
col3.Add "e"   'col1.Item(2)(2)
col3.Add "f"   'col1.Item(2)(3)
col3.Add col3  'col1.Item(2)(4)
```

I wouldn't recommend using such a recursive data structure (i.e. adding a collection to itself).

Comment: I did this completely accidentally, but a good lesson learned.  Thank you for this, and thank you for several other posts of yours, to other folks, which I came across on this forum.  I've learned a lot of good stuff from them.

Comment: @Marek you have no idea how much this comment means to me - thank *you*!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I better go back and do the same for the other question I posted.  Never knew you have to do that.

Comment: It also bears noting that such cyclic references can cause memory leak problems. Even though in the code we've set the 3 variables to `Nothing`, what really happened is that we've detached the collection from our VBA code's reach so it's now just floating in the nether region of memory. For a big enough collection, that is seen as slower slowdown when the runtime realizes there's a dark blob of memory that nobody's using. To avoid this, it would have been necessary to do the equivalent of `Set col1.Item(X) = Nothing` for both collection references before releasing the 3 collections.